# For a given month, pick the value of entire quarter - Dax Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I have a table like this:

```html
Goods Month Quarter
12    July Q1
13    Oct  Q2
76    Sep  Q1
56    Dec  Q2
```

In my Power BI dashboard, I have a slicer through which I can select a month. There are few visuals in which i need to show monthly data but in 1 visual I need to show data of the entire quarter (Note: Not quarter by date) but of the entire quarter. Even if i select January, it should show me value of the entire quarter.
I tried QTD functions but I want entire quarter.

How can i get that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

assuming this is all in the single table:

```
Measure = 
VAR _quarter =
    MAX ( 'Table'[Quarter] )
RETURN
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Table'[Goods] ),
    'Table'[Quarter] = _quarter,
    REMOVEFILTERS ( 'Table'[Month] )
)
```

If Table[Month] has custom sort to have calendar order it also needs to be added in REMOVEFILTERS

Answer (score 0):

Create a measure as below-

```
quarter_value = 

SWITCH(
    ISFILTERED (your_table_name[Month]),
    TRUE(),
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(your_table_name[Goods]),
        FILTER(
            ALL(your_table_name),
            your_table_name[Quarter] = MIN(your_table_name[Quarter])
        )
    ),
    sum(your_table_name[Goods]) 
)
```

here is the output when nothing is selected in the filter-

[image]

and here is the output is some value is selected in the filter-

[image]